# Mule ActiveMQ at particular time interval

Tags: mule, activemq-classic

I have a scenario wherein I need to start receiving messages from Queue after a particular time interval irrespective of time the message is placed in queue.

For example **Flow A** process some service calls and then place the below message in queue

```
{
   filename:"blahblah.pdf"
}
```

Now **Flow B** need to start recieving the messages from queue after 9PM(or some time) daily and then process it.

I wonder is it possible to achieve this scenario in Mule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Mulesoft using [Poll Scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/poll-reference) or [Quartz Schedular](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/quartz-connector).
Code will be some thing like

```
<quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="ReadQIN"
    cronExpression="* * * * * ?"  doc:name="Quartz">
    <quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
        <quartz:job-endpoint address="jms://QIN" />
    </quartz:endpoint-polling-job>
</quartz:inbound-endpoint>
```

Comment: Thanks Anupam for quick response, can I give Active MQ address in the quartz job endpoint??

Comment: You can provide any endpoint like file, sftp, vm, jms, activemq

Comment: Thanks Anupam its working!!! but only one message is recieved even though there are n messages in queue, what if i want to recieve all messages at once and then process